# How to update all records that were created yesterday with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

I need to update the info on all records that were created yesterday, for that I created a `migration` with the following code:

```
class UpdateFbidToVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Vote.all.each do |v|
      if v.created_at == Date.today-1
        v.fbid = v.fbid + 1
        v.update!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This, however, doesn't work. Can you please point me to what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need migration for that and `Vote.all` is fetching all the records and your if condition filters them which can happen through a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
yesterday = 1.day.ago # or Time.now.yesterday
Vote.where(created_at: yesterday.beginning_of_day..yesterday.end_of_day).update_all('fbid = fbid + 1')
```

Also, migration files are meant for managing table schema, I'd encourage you to move such db update/delete queries to a rake task instead of migration file, such queries are not reversible(i.e. you can not rely on getting the changes back to previous state) and should not be a part of migrations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using rake task. Did do that and your solution worked fine! :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Vote.where(created_at: Date.yesterday).update_all('fbid = fbid + 1')
```

Comment: Identifier quoting rules are database dependent. Standard SQL and PostgreSQL use double quotes, MySQL uses backticks, SQL Server uses brackets, ... Probably best not to quote them at all.